# PHP Zip extension is not available in windows 10 with XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, windows-10, zip, prestashop

I have a problem with php 8.2.4 in `XAMPP xampp-windows-x64-8.2.4-0-VS16-installer` with **ZIP_Extension** for windows 10. I have a .dll package downloaded, in the **php.ini** file at `;extension=zip` I removed the semicolon, even replaced `=zip` with `=php_zip.dll`. However, the function `extension_loaded('zip')` strenuously returns false, as if this package does not exist.

I can't install PrestaShop version 8.1.1 or any other package because of this.

According to the `PHP 8.x.x` documentation, this package is already built-in, but still, I can't enable it

Have any of you already had this problem?

Comment: Did you restart the web server after making changes to `php.ini`?

Comment: And be aware extension_dir should be absolute in apache.

Comment: If that extension is missing, are you sure this is directly related to PrestaShop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrestaShop 8.1.1 is not compatible with PHP 8.2. The maximum version you can use is 8.1. You can see all the requirements here:

https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/basics/installation/system-requirements/

After modifying the php.ini file, remember to reload the webserver when dealing with ZIP extensions.

Comment: Then I have another question for you:
Have you encountered an error where the process of installing a PrestaShop store is 0% and crashes with a message: `Create file parameters` and underneath: `1: HTTP 500 - error -. `

Comment: It might be related to the SSL configuration on Windows. You can check this article:
https://build.prestashop-project.org/news/2023/core-monthly-2023-07-01-2023-07-31/

"PrestaShop 8.1.1. The first patch version and upgrade issues." paragraph.